# Unset setgid bit with chmod numeric mode

Tags: debian, directory, chmod, setgid

I've just noticed some interesting behavior with `chmod` when unsetting the setgid bit:

```
$ mkdir test
$ chmod 2755 test
$ stat -c '%a %n' test
2755 test  # as expected
$ chmod 0755 test
$ stat -c '%a %n' test
2755 test  # what? see below
$ chmod 00755 test
$ stat -c '%a %n' test
755 test  # double what?!
```

Attempting to unset the setgid bit with `chmod 0755` doesn't work, which is surprising. However, the man page indicates that this is the intended behavior:

> SETUID AND SETGID BITS
>
> chmod clears the set-group-ID bit of a regular file if the file's group
>   ID  does  not  match the user's effective group ID or one of the user's
>   supplementary group IDs, unless the user  has  appropriate  privileges.
>   Additional restrictions may cause the set-user-ID and set-group-ID bits
>   of MODE or RFILE to be ignored.  This behavior depends  on  the  policy
>   and  functionality of the underlying chmod system call.  When in doubt,
>   check the underlying system behavior.
>
> chmod preserves a directory's set-user-ID and set-group-ID bits  unless
>   you  explicitly  specify otherwise.  You can set or clear the bits with
>   symbolic modes like u+s and g-s, and **you can set (but  not  clear)  the
>   bits with a numeric mode.**

(Emphasis added)

So it seems `chmod 0755` isn't meant to unset the setgid bit. Why, then, however, does `chmod 00755` unset it? `chmod` doesn't seem to have any use for **five** digits of a numeric mode. Again from the man page:

> A numeric mode is from **one to four** octal digits (0-7), derived by
>   adding up the bits with values 4, 2, and 1. Omitted digits are assumed
>   to be leading zeroes.

(Emphasis added)

What's going on here? Why would `chmod` decide to ignore a single leading 0? Why does it *not* ignore two leading 0's?

(Debian Stretch 9.1, with chmod (GNU Coreutils) 8.6)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've found it! This info is missing from the man page but is in the Coreutils manual online. To wit:

> On most systems, if a directory’s set-group-ID bit is set, newly
>   created subfiles inherit the same group as the directory, and newly
>   created subdirectories inherit the set-group-ID bit of the parent
>   directory. On a few systems, a directory’s set-user-ID bit has a
>   similar effect on the ownership of new subfiles and the set-user-ID
>   bits of new subdirectories. These mechanisms let users share files
>   more easily, by lessening the need to use `chmod` or `chown` to share new
>   files.
>
> These convenience mechanisms rely on the set-user-ID and set-group-ID
>   bits of directories. If commands like `chmod` and `mkdir` routinely
>   cleared these bits on directories, the mechanisms would be less
>   convenient and it would be harder to share files. Therefore, a command
>   like `chmod` does not affect the set-user-ID or set-group-ID bits of a
>   directory unless the user specifically mentions them in a symbolic
>   mode, or uses an operator numeric mode such as ‘=755’, or sets them in
>   a numeric mode, or clears them in a numeric mode that has five or more
>   octal digits.

Reference: https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Directory-Setuid-and-Setgid.html

Comment: (So, as is often the case in these weird "problems"--it's a GNU extension.)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a bug in the chmod in Debian Stretch 9.1?  It works as it should on Ubuntu 12.04, Ubuntu 16.04.3, CentOS 6.9 and CentOS 7.4.

Comment: When you say "works as it should" you mean `00755` *doesn't* unset the setgid bit or `0755` *does* unset the setgid bit?

Comment: To be fair, I didn't try 00755, but `chmod 0755 testfile` does clear the setgid bit on the above 4 systems I tried.

Comment: What is `chmod --version`? My system has it from GNU Coreutils 8.26.

Comment: Ahh `chmod 0755` works on files but not on directories. Even more interesting!

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04: 8.13; Ubuntu 16.04.3: 8.25; CentOS 6.9: 8.4; CentOS 7.4: 8.22

Comment: Ooh, good spot. I missed the bit initially about it being a directory - and on my CentOS 7.4 box I do indeed need to use 00755 to clear the setgid bit on the directory.